# Power BI DAX - Filter All Columns from a Table Based on What-If Parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Context:

I have a table named "RunData" with dozens of columns, which I'd like to filter based on the value in the "RunNum" column based on a what-if parameter slider slicer. The result needs to be a table because are multiple rows that match the parameter, and I'd like the data from all the columns in the original table.

So I'd like to dynamically extract a subset of rows from my original table when I change the slider.

What I have tried:

Creating a measure `Measure = SELECTEDVALUE('RunData'[RunNum]) = 4` and then a table based on that measure defined as `FilteredTable = Filter('RunData',[Measure])` works exactly as intended.

But updating the measure to not have the filter value hard coded (i.e. 4) but rather be the output of the what-if parameter breaks the functionality.

Following option all result in an empty FilteredTable:

```
Measure = SELECTEDVALUE('RunData'[RunNum]) = SELECTEDVALUE(RunFilter[RunFilter])
Measure = SELECTEDVALUE('RunData'[RunNum]) = RunFilter[RunFilterValue]
```

==============

In simpler terms, a filtered table using a hard-coded value works:

```
FilteredTable = FILTER(RunData,RunData[RunNum]=4)
```

But one based on a parameter does not. Any way to get around this?

```
FilteredTable = FILTER(RunData,RunData[RunNum]=SELECTEDVALUE(Parameter[Parameter]))
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but may it be something like  

FilteredTable = Filter('RunData','RunNum'=SELECTEDVALUE(RunFilter[RunFilter]))?

Comment: Your suggestion is the direct route for what I've been trying to do. The issue is "SELECTEDVALUE(RunFilter[RunFilter]))" doesn't yield a single value in these applications and results in an empty table. If you replace it with a hardcoded value (i.e. =4 ) it works as intended. I'm wondering if a dynamically filtered table is possible to generate.